# a2billing change value before writing to .conf

Tags: php, asterisk

I'm in the process of hashing values in a2b DB,
I'm trying to change the value of 'secret' field before it is written to additional_a2billing_sip.conf.

I cannot find the exact location where the writing takes place so I can't edit the value, and therefore the hash is written to the .conf instead of a plain-text value.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is not what you trying to do.

A2billing also support sip realtime.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip

If you still want use files, you can check code in a2billing web on pressing button

Comment: If you could elaborate more on why this is a 'bad' solution?

Comment: becuase "nice" solution is use sip realtime/views in database.